# Persistence probability for simple random walk

Tags: probability, random-variables, brownian-motion, random-walk

Consider a discrete-time symmetric simple random walk in $\mathbb{Z}$ starting from the origin. How does the probability that the simple random walk stays positive up to time $n \in \mathbb{N}$ decays with $n$? How can I estimate this probability?

Comment: Stays positive means that it doesn't hit the origin, right? (Or can it hit the origin without going negative?) Either way, your problem seems to be related to Dyck paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S_n$ be the position of the random walk after $n$ steps. By the [reflection principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_principle_(Wiener_process)) and the [Ballot theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem), it follows that
$$
P(S_1 S_2 \cdots S_n \neq 0) = \frac{1}{n} E |S_n|.
$$
Now (see for example [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/334000/expectation-of-the-absolute-value-in-a-sequence-of-bernoulli-trials)) we have
$$
E |S_n| \sim \sqrt{\frac{2n}{\pi}},
$$
so the probability you are wondering about decays as $O(n^{-1/2})$.